# Synonyms for "to place on top of"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a succinct verb for the act of putting something on top of something else? I'm looking for something more vivid than a simple *put* or *place*.

> I **xxx**'d the letter on the pile of bills.

Comment: I don't see how you can get a much more succinct verb than "put". Saying "put X on Y" implies *on top of Y*.

Comment: Why the down votes? I received some great synonyms for a word that is difficult to look up in a thesaurus.

Comment: @Jen, part of the problem is that your question is somewhat self-contradictory: you want something succinct, but then immediately discard the most likely candidates as not *vivid* enough. It could help to clarify which aspect is most important to you: succinctness or vividness? Also, you might want to explain why looking up "put" and "place" in a thesaurus did not yield an answer.

Comment: *Put* and *place* are hard to look up as they are general and have a multitude of applications. The accepted answer (*toss*) is both succinct and vivid. Thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "toss"? That was what my brain filled in when I read your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

There's *stacked*, and you could say you *added* the letter to the pile.

Additional reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1f-kfRREA8M

Answer (score 1):

I would say *piled* but that sounds bad in the context of your example. I'd choose between some flavor of *stack* or *pile* - "I piled the letter on top of all the bills" - and using some flavor of *put* or *place* - "I put the letter on the pile of bills".

stack - Arrange (a number of things) in a pile, typically a neat one: "the books had been stacked up in three piles".

put - Move to or place in a particular position: "Harry put down his cup"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the verb *lay* (past tense *laid*).

Answer (score 1):

Some variations with various nuances:

- *I balanced the letter carefully atop the pile of bills.*
- *I slammed the letter down, onto the pile of bills.*
- *I deposited the letter on the pile of bills.*
- *I dropped the letter into the mess of bills and stirred them all about.*